# Mono Android - Display dialog even when application is not in focused

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I was wondering if there is a way to display an alert dialog even when your application is minimized/not focused.

I'm creating a small alert system app for a small company. I'm using Xamarin. Don't really have to worry about old API Levels, every phone is 15+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't show an alert but you can start an activity that is styled as a dialog (transparent background + your content in the middle). To do this start the activity as a new task. Example:

```
startActivity(new Intent(context, YourActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

This proved to work on all devices as long as it's not in standby with a secure lock - password for example.